# Ionic: image not showing over background image

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a page background image and am trying to place another image over it however it is not displaying for some reason

My code is as follows

```css
.page-background {
    background-image: url('../assets/imgs/Splash Screen Image.png');
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.page-top-img {
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<ion-content padding class="page-background">
    <img src="assets/imgs/MasterCard.svg" alt="" class="page-top-img" />
</ion-content>
```

I am currently only seeing the background image

Comment: Have you give the path correctly once you sea the path whatever you're giving in URL.

Comment: yes you are correct, path was not correct, chrome did not give an error too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this location is correct **../assets/imgs/Splash Screen Image.png** then remove space in file name **Splash_Screen_Image.png** or check your location image is available are not? and remove z-index when you are using position relative and absolute.

```
<ion-content padding class="page-background">
      <img src="assets/imgs/MasterCard.svg" alt="" class="page-top-img" />
    </ion-content>

    .page-background{
      background-image: url('../assets/imgs/Splash_Screen_Image.png');
      background-size: cover;
      position : relative;
    }
    .page-top-img{
      position:absolute;
      left:50px;
      top: 50px;
      width:100%; /* set your width size */
      height:100px; /* set your height size */ 
    }
```